# keras and tensorflow(backend error) Tensor conv2d_1_input:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras

I was using keras and tensorfoow and i'm completely new to it.
I had trained my models and when i make to predict it the error is showing.
This is the code i have used for the image prediction

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import numpy
from PIL import Image
import os
import tensorflow.keras
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from keras.models import load_model

app = Flask(__name__)

model = load_model('traffic_classifier.h5')
model._make_predict_function()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Main page
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/traffic')
def traffic():
    # Main page
    return render_template('traffic.html')

@app.route('/sleep')
def sleep():
    # Main page
    return render_template('sleep.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    '''
    For rendering results on HTML GUI
    '''



    classes = { 1:'Speed limit (20km/h)',
            2:'Speed limit (30km/h)',      
            3:'Speed limit (50km/h)',       
            4:'Speed limit (60km/h)',      
            5:'Speed limit (70km/h)',    
            6:'Speed limit (80km/h)',      
            7:'End of speed limit (80km/h)',     
            8:'Speed limit (100km/h)',    
            9:'Speed limit (120km/h)',     
           10:'No passing',   
           11:'No passing veh over 3.5 tons',     
           12:'Right-of-way at intersection',     
           13:'Priority road',    
           14:'Yield',     
           15:'Stop',       
           16:'No vehicles',       
           17:'Veh > 3.5 tons prohibited',       
           18:'No entry',       
           19:'General caution',     
           20:'Dangerous curve left',      
           21:'Dangerous curve right',   
           22:'Double curve',      
           23:'Bumpy road',     
           24:'Slippery road',       
           25:'Road narrows on the right',  
           26:'Road work',    
           27:'Traffic signals',      
           28:'Pedestrians',     
           29:'Children crossing',     
           30:'Bicycles crossing',       
           31:'Beware of ice/snow',
           32:'Wild animals crossing',      
           33:'End speed + passing limits',      
           34:'Turn right ahead',     
           35:'Turn left ahead',       
           36:'Ahead only',      
           37:'Go straight or right',      
           38:'Go straight or left',      
           39:'Keep right',     
           40:'Keep left',      
           41:'Roundabout mandatory',     
           42:'End of no passing',      
           43:'End no passing veh > 3.5 tons' }




    if request. method == "POST":
        #image=request. form["fileupload"]

        f = request.files['file']

        # Save the file to ./uploads
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        file_path = os.path.join(
            basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(file_path)  


    image = Image.open(file_path)
    image = image.resize((30,30))
    image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = numpy.array(image)

    pred = model.predict_classes([image])[0]

    sign = classes[pred+1]





    return render_template('traffic.html', prediction_text='This sign represents {}'.format(sign))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm getting error

**tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError**
**tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Tensor conv2d_1_input:0, specified in** **either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph**

what to do with it??

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding these codes

```
config = tensorflow.ConfigProto(
    device_count={'GPU': 1},
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
    allow_soft_placement=True
)

config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.6

session = tensorflow.Session(config=config)
keras.backend.set_session(session)

model = load_model('traffic_classifier.h5')
model._make_predict_function()
```

Comment: after running this code i am having this error :

Error while reading resource variable block5_conv1/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/block5_conv1/kernel)
  [[{{node block5_conv1_1/convolution/ReadVariableOp}}]]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Flask is using threads. This means that for each request, Flask creates a new thread. As such, your model is not visible from the request.

To solve this problem, you need to make the model part of a global session that is used throughout.

The solution can be found here as this [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28287#issuecomment-495005162).

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model

tf_config = some_custom_config
sess = tf.Session(config=tf_config)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# IMPORTANT: models have to be loaded AFTER SETTING THE SESSION for keras! 
# Otherwise, their weights will be unavailable in the threads after the session there has been set
set_session(sess)
model = load_model(...)
```

then, inside your method:

```
def predict():
    ....
    global sess
    global graph
    with graph.as_default():
    set_session(sess)
    pred = model.predict_classes(...)
    ...
```